# Using ComplexPlot Command

Tags: plotting, complex

I have been trying to make my function below work but it keeps giving a blank output,

Please help.

```
Subscript[Z, 0] = 377;
Subscript[Z, b] = 123.62317;
Subscript[k, b] = Entity["Character", "U+03C9"]*Sqrt[Entity["Character", "U+03BC"]*Entity["Character", "U+03F5"]];
ComplexPlot[-((4 e^(h I Subscript[k, b]) Subscript[Z, 0] Subscript[Z, b])/(-\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(Z\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) + e^(2 h I Subscript[k, b]) \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(Z\), \(0\), \(2\)]\) - 2 Subscript[Z, 0] Subscript[Z, b] - 2 e^(2 h I Subscript[k, b]) Subscript[Z, 0] Subscript[Z, b] - \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(Z\), \(b\), \(2\)]\) +  e^(2 h I Subscript[k, b]) \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(Z\), \(b\), \(2\)]\))), {h, 0, 10 + 10 I}]
```

Comment: Use `E` rather than `e` for the exponential constant.

Comment: @BobHanlon Tried, still a blank output

Comment: `Subscript[k, b]` is not numeric. (BTW why do you define a variable like this? )

Comment: @xzczd What if those variables are constants? Do I still need to define?

Comment: Those `Entity[…]`s are just strange. Are you trying to input greek letters as variables? Then the correct way is e.g. Esc+o+Esc.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Assigning arbitrary values to the undefined constants.

```
ω = 1; μ = 1; ϵ = 1;

Subscript[Z, 0] = 377;
Subscript[Z, b] = 123.62317;
Subscript[k, b] = ω*Sqrt[μ*ϵ];

ComplexPlot[-((4 E^(h I Subscript[k, b]) Subscript[Z, 0] Subscript[Z, 
       b])/(-Subscript[Z, 0]^2 + 
      E^(2 h I Subscript[k, b]) Subscript[Z, 0]^2 - 
      2 Subscript[Z, 0] Subscript[Z, b] - 
      2 E^(2 h I Subscript[k, b]) Subscript[Z, 0] Subscript[Z, b] - 
      Subscript[Z, b]^2 +  E^(2 h I Subscript[k, b]) Subscript[Z, b]^2)), {h, 
  0, 10 + 10 I}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @BobHanlon, what about if I were to log or abs the whole function? It would still work?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I did and it kept showing errors

Comment: Did you use my code? I did not get any errors with either `Log` or `Abs`. If you get errors, always report the specific errors that you get.